# Need to include #anchor after querystring list

Tags: javascript, html, http-get

Form is 'get' to a API which operates off of querystring.

One of the parameters is a PackageID which indicates a vacation package. In order for the packageID to appear I also need to append '#packages' to the end of the get request.

Since not all form 'get' have a package I need this to be dynamic. I've tried adding a hidden field with '#packages' as the value - however the '#' is automatically encoded and therefore not registered when the server grabs the URL.

What would be the best way for me to dynamically include '#packages' as it appears in the querystring via javascript? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't *dynamically* append an anchor by using a regular form submit.

You could intercept the submit event and change the target attribute of the form to a URL that includes the anchor. At least in Firefox, the browser will insert the query string in the right place (before the anchor.)

For example:

```
<form action="test.htm" method="get" onsubmit="this.action += '#anchor'">
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

*(Note: This is for illustration purposes. I wouldn't include the submit event handler inline with my HTML.)*

Alternatively, you could try constructing your very own URL (including the query string and the anchor) and then setting `document.location` to that.